# I keep returning the same value for variable howMany

Tags: c++, file, struct, header

I have a file that has been previously filled with data. The file consists of an array of structures. Each structure represents a round and each array position represents up to 20 rounds for an individual. My .h file:

```
define READTWENTY_H

class readTwenty {

public:
    readTwenty();
    void nonZeroes(int, int &);

   struct a_round {
    int score;
    double course_rating;
    int slope;
    char date[15];
    char place[40];
    char mark[1];
    }; //end structure definition

    struct a_round all_info[20];

FILE *fptr;

}; //end class
#endif
```

In the data file some "rounds" have actual data in them and some have previously been filled with zeroes. I want to count the zero rounds. I have a loop in which I can ask for another "person" value to look at. This value is sent to a function in which the number of zero rounds is determined and returned by reference to a variable named "howMany".

```
// readMember.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
```

//

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "readTwenty.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int person = 0;
    readTwenty personData;
    int howMany = 0;

while (person != -999) {
    cout << "Which member (keyfield)  would you like to see? -999 to stop ";
    cin >> person;

    if (person == -999)
        exit(0);

    personData.nonZeroes(person-1, howMany);
    cout << "The number of non-zero values for this member is " << howMany << endl;
}//end while

return 0;
}
```

Once sent to the nonzeroes function as "key" I create an offset into the file and read the 20 rounds for that individual and return by reference the value of count back to the calling routine into variable howMany.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "readTwenty.h"
#include <errno.h>
#include <cstdio>

readTwenty::readTwenty() {
const char *configfile;
configfile = "scores.dat";

#ifdef WIN32
   errno_t err;

if((err = fopen_s(&fptr,configfile, "rb")) != 0)
   #else
if ((fp_config = fopen(configfile, "rb")) == NULL)
#endif
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open cinfig file %s!\n", configfile);

   }//end constructor

void readTwenty::nonZeroes(int key, int &count) {

int zeroes = 0;

int offset = key * ((sizeof(all_info[0]) * 20));
fseek(fptr, offset, SEEK_SET);

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    fread(&all_info[i], sizeof(all_info[0]), 1, fptr);
    if (all_info[i].score == 0)
       zeroes++;
   all_info[i].mark[0] = ' ';
  }//end for loop

count = 20 - zeroes;
fclose(fptr);

}//end of function nonZeroes
```

The problem is that the first value that I give for person comes back with the correct number of non-zero rounds. However, each succeeding iteration of the while loop regardless of the second value I give for person comes back with the same result as the first person? Would greatly appreciate any ideas you may have.

Comment: You're in luck. On your computer there's a tool called a "debugger", that let you step through your code, one line at a time, and examine the values of all variables. With the debugger's assistance, as it steps through the loop, you should be able to figure out your problem in no time at all.

Answer (score 0):

I currently have no computer to verify, but one line jumps out to me as it is a common error (for me at least):

The first param to your `fread` is `&all_info[i]`; you probably want `&(all_info[i])`, but this is not how the compiler understands it - `&` is stronger than `[i]`, so you get `(&all_info)[i]`.

You could also use `all_info+i` for the same effect.

Comment: Thank you! My values of variables person, key and offset all seem to change with each iteration, but the value of howMany keeps coming back to the calling routine the same each time?

Comment: Just to let you know that I found the problem. In my function nonZeroes (at the end of the function) I close the file pointer and thus with each new iteration the file pointer is closed. My question is should I leave the file open or close at the end of each iteration and then re-open with maybe a final close in main()?